# Seeing bundle files path in login url and redirecting multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using mvc4 and .Net 4.5 in my project with SSL. Now, on localhost and even on server, the login page gets redirect a bunch of times and then loads without and css on page. In browser debugger I get error as:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <http://localhost:55248/Account/Login?    ReturnUrl=%2fbundles%2fjqueryval%3fv%3dWrBNyT_GYLXAZ7iWD7vDdFccq24m7v_9MPi3rcQ8FO01&v=WrBNyT_GYLXAZ7iWD7vDdFccq24m7v_9MPi3rcQ8FO01...`

I'm using bundling and code snippet as below.

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/BaseJs")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is from the error page being loaded as JavaScript (when it's obviously not JavaScript). It's a red herring. The true problem is that your JavaScript file is needing authorization in the first place.

Typically, this wouldn't be an issue. By default, anything with an extension (`.js`, for example) is ignored by MVC and handled directly by IIS. Worst case scenario, there, IIS doesn't have permission to read the file, and you end up with a 403 Forbidden. It would end there, as an IIS-level 403 would not trigger a login page redirect, mostly because, again, MVC is not involved.

However, if you've bungled around the with default setup, such that MVC is now handling *all* requests, even for static files. Then, the action that's being triggered to handle the request to your JavaScript file is requiring authorization, and therefore is redirecting to the login page. So find out what action is being hit and either remove the requirement for it to be authorized or have the right action serve the file. Or, ideally, leave things as they should be and let IIS do what IIS does best and serve the static files.

**EDIT**

I wasn't paying attention to the fact that bundles are rendered without a file extension. However, the steps to correct the issue are largely the same. Something is mostly likely off with your routing, and the request for the bundle is actually being caught by one of your actions, particularly one that requires authorization. Look out for catch-all routes and make sure that you're not using a route like "bundles" anywhere in your RouteConfig.cs or any of your `Route` attributes, if you're using attribute routing.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt. I'm not using any route expecting "bundles" in it. I'll make the changes recommended here and get back with the results.

Answer (score -1):

First try to include your bundles like that :

```
.Include(  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
            );
```

Include takes string[] as parameter and you don't need to call include for each row. Then you should debug your bundles to see which js is giving the error.

Try to comment out rows 1 by 1 to see what would be the result. The problem is definatelly in your bundles, I also had these kind of errors. If you can provide more code - > snippet from the view, of the css loading and bundles and stuff like that I would be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks @dlght. I'll make the changes and get back to you with more details.